# For $V = \sum_{s=1}^{t} A_s A_{s}^T$ to be non-singular $(A_s)_{s=1}^{t}$ needs to span $R^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am reading a book on bandits algorithm and inside a proof it says the following:

Let $(A_s)_{s=1}^{t}$ be sequence of vectors in $R^d$. Construct a matrix $V$ such that:

$$ V =  \sum_{s=1}^{t} A_s A_{s}^T$$

Now for $V$ to be non-singular, $(A_s)_{s=1}^{t}$ must span $R^d$ and $t$ must be at least $d$.

I can see why $t$ needs to be at least $d$ but I am not sure how to prove that $(A_s)_{s=1}^{t}$ must span $R^d$.

Any help in understanding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $V$ to be non-singular, it has to have rank $d$. That means that the rows (or columns, whichever you prefer) span all of $R^d$. Taking a close look at these columns, you will see that every single column is a linear combination of the $A_s$. Hence, the rows of $V$ span at most the same space as the $A_s$.